# Why is this Jekyll parses markdown in posts but NOT pages?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have [this](http://equalitytime.github.io/CommuniKate/translation.html) Jekyll site for an open project that I am part of.

It's sitting on gh-Pages (you can see all the files [here](https://github.com/eQualityTime/CommuniKate/tree/gh-pages), and the problem happens both there and locally.

For each post, like [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eQualityTime/CommuniKate/gh-pages/_posts/2014-09-23-main-3.markdown, the markdown renders perfectly and displays what I want.

[image]

However, I also have a file called translation.md in the root directory ([raw version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eQualityTime/CommuniKate/gh-pages/translation.md).

This appears like this:

[image]

Which is... sub optimial.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `page.content` with `content` in `_layouts/singlepage.html`, so Jekyll process the markdown correctly:

```
  ....
  <div class="lead">
         {{content}}
  </div>
  ...
```